# Linking a \foreach loop to start from a specific node position

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the following code, I manually have made the \foreach loop starts from the location of the center of node B.

How can I automatically start the \foreach loop at the center of node B, so that when I would like to edit the code to change its location, the \foreach loop would start from the new location without the need to redefine its starting position at (3,\X).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\newsavebox{\recBBr}
\savebox{\recBBr}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw [thick, black, fill=red!60!white] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1.24*1.68);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\draw [line width=.4mm, black, dashed](0,0) -- (11,0) node [pos=.28] (B) {\Large B};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \X in {0,1.5,3,4.5}
{\node[blue, yshift=.64cm] (y-\X) at (3,\X){\usebox{\recBBr}};}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use calc library and define starting position at `($(B)+(0,\X)$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

Use the coordinate `(B|-0,\X)`, which finds the intersection between a vertical line through `(B)` and an horizontal one through `(0,\X)`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\newsavebox{\recBBr}
\savebox{\recBBr}{% <-- important so you don't get extra space in the box
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw [thick, black, fill=red!60!white] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1.24*1.68);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\draw [line width=.4mm, black, dashed](0,0) -- (11,0) node [pos=.28,font=\Large] (B) {B};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \foreach \X in {0,1.5,3,4.5}
 {\node[blue,yshift=.64cm] (y-\X) at (B|-0,\X){\usebox{\recBBr}};}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2

Use `foreach` inside a path starting from `B`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\newsavebox{\recBBr}
\savebox{\recBBr}{% <-- important so you don't get extra space in the box
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw [thick, black, fill=red!60!white] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1.24*1.68);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\draw [line width=.4mm, black, dashed](0,0) -- (11,0) node [pos=.28,font=\Large] (B) {B};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]

\path
  (B)
  \foreach \X in {1,...,4} {
    node[blue,yshift=.64cm] (y-\X) {\usebox{\recBBr}}
    ++(0,1.5)
  };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that this gives you more natural naming for the `(y-N)` nodes, plus it feels more readable.
The `++(0,1.5)` indicates the shift since the last coordinate in the past, which feels more intuitive and is easier to change than manually providing the `y` values in the list of the loop.

---

In both cases the box had an extra initial space that would have resulted in unwanted x-shift in the rectangle boxes. It has been removed by commenting the newline.

Comment: @BordaigorlThank you very much. The first option is simpler and more precise

Comment: More precise how? I actually prefer the second one!

Comment: @BordaigorlWhen I edited the shift of the boxes, I understood what you meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only to draw image, which you show in your question, than I would draw your image on the following way:

- first draw red boxes
- after than determine start dashed line relstive to south coordinate of the lovest box
- in drawing is handy to use `chains` and `positioning` libraries
- for drawing red boxes is not needed `savebox`, instead it is simpler to define style for red boxes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 32mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {draw,  thick, fill=red!60!white, 
                 minimum width=6mm, minimum height=12mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0mm,
                 on chain}
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \node (n\i) [box] {};
\coordinate[left=of n4.south] (a);
\draw [line width=.4mm, dashed]
    (a) -- ++ (11,0);  
\node[font=\Large] at (n4.south) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ZarkoThank you very much