# Combining 2 \foreach loops into one

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the following code (from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504503/linking-a-foreach-loop-to-start-from-a-specific-node-position)) to draw boxes using 2 \foreach loops; and defining the starting positions of both of them (yshift=.4cm and yshift=4.4cm).  I want the blue boxes to automatically begin where the red boxes end.

Is it possible to combine them into one loop.

I mean using one \foreach loop to draw the lower 4 red boxes then continue with the upper 2 blue boxes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\newsavebox{\recAr}
\savebox{\recAr}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw [thick, black, fill=red] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1.24);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newsavebox{\recAb}
\savebox{\recAb}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw [thick, black, fill=blue!60!white] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1.24);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\draw [line width=.4mm, black, dashed] (0,5.8) -- +(0:11) (0,0) -- +(0:11) node [pos=.68] (A) {};
\foreach \X in {0,1,2,3}
{\node[yshift=.4cm] (y-\X) at (A|-0,\X){\usebox{\recAr}};}
\foreach \X in {0,1}
{\node[yshift=4.4cm] (y-\X) at (A|-0,\X){\usebox{\recAb}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible by performing a test, but what is the point of doing that?

Comment: To avoid using 2 loops and manually adding spacing between the red boxes and blue ones; which have to be adjusted if the boxes dimensions have to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With partial loop only and based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504503/linking-a-foreach-loop-to-start-from-a-specific-node-position/504518#504518) the solution is simple:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t, fragile]
\frametitle{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 55mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {draw,  thick, fill=#1,
                 minimum width=6mm, minimum height=12mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0mm,
                 on chain}
                        ] 
\node (n1) [box=blue] {};
\node (n2) [box=blue] {};
    \node (n3) [below=1ex of n2, % when you need additional space, otherwide omit this option
                box=red] {}; %
\foreach \i in {4,5,6}
    \node (n\i) [box=red] {};
\coordinate[left=of n1.north] (a); % for shift node to the right
\draw [line width=.4mm, dashed]
    (a) -- ++ (11,0)  
    (a |- n6.south) -- ++ (11,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ZarkoThank you very much for your answer. Just one comment. Can the red boxes dimensions be different from the blue boxes. I mean separate their definitions.

Comment: @Hany as I already mentioned, please limit your scope of your question, please dont add constraints on-the-fly.

Comment: @Hany, of course it is possible.You only need to define two styles for boxes. However, from your question I'm not able to figure out the context of image, i.e. what you like to present. Structure of your code is (to my opinion) u necessary complex and unclear.

Comment: @ZarkoThank you very much. I defined 2 styles for the boxes, and it works fine. This is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

**Added `Dunno's` recommendation to make the solution as per the OP's requirements**

You can simply loop the variables over:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\newsavebox{\recAr}
\savebox{\recAr}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw [thick, black, fill=red] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1.24);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newsavebox{\recAb}
\savebox{\recAb}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw [thick, black, fill=blue!60!white] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1.24);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\draw [line width=.4mm, black, dashed] (0,5.8) -- +(0:11) (0,0) -- +(0:11) coordinate[pos=.68,alias=y-6] (A) {}; \path foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially 6)] in {5,4,...,0}{ node[above=1.5mm of y-\LastX,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] (y-\X) {\ifnum \X>3 \usebox{\recAb} \else \usebox{\recAr} \fi}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

PS: I made the code in such a manner that only one `yshift` is necessary, thereby, making the `yshift` common for both the blue and red boxes.

Comment: @RaajaThank you. But this does not solve the problem of manually adding spacing between the red boxes and blue ones; which have to be adjusted if the boxes dimensions have to be changed; by defining yshift=.4cm and yshift=4.4cm

Comment: @Hany based on your question, I understood that you wanted to make it into a single loop. Could you make it explicit in your question. The information you just provided is missing.

Comment: @RaajaPlease refer to my edited question. I want to avoid defining the starting position of the blue boxes, in case I have to change their dimensions. I want the blue boxes to automatically begin where the red boxes end.

Comment: @Hany Let me know whether this new answer would suit you.

Comment: @RaajaThank you for your time; but if you change the dimensions of the red boxes, the starting position of the blue boxes is not adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @Dunno True, I will edit my answer. Was lazy to make the changes.

Comment: @Hany Please avoid adding newer constraints to your question :) if possible collate all your constraints first and the post a question. Because when you started you wanted to make a single-loop, then you wanted to adjust the spacing and now some dimensional corrections. Please try to stick to the question's scope and avoid renewing your questions on-the-fly.

Comment: @RaajaYour last edited answer is very good. Just one comment. Why does the boxes start above and end below the dashed lines. They should start and end just between them. Thank you.

Comment: @Hany you can reverse the queue yourself to achieve what you want. And for the last part, I consider that as out-of-scope of this question. May be it's better if you ask a new question for that part.