# Positioning 2 \foreach loops in 2 different locations

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504541/combining-2-foreach-loops-into-one)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape,
node distance = 1mm and 60mm,
  start chain = going below,
   boxa/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=7.1mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.96mm,
             on chain},
   boxb/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=7.1mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.96mm,
             on chain},
   boxc/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=12.7mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.6mm,
             on chain},
]
\draw [line width=.4mm, black, dashed] (0,5.8) -- +(0:11) (0,0) -- +(0:11) node [pos=.28] (B) {\Large B} node [pos=.68] (A) {\Large A};

\node at ([shift={(90:5.4cm)}]A.center) (n1) [boxa=blue!60!white] {};
\node (n2) [boxa=blue!60!white] {};
\foreach \i in {3,...,6}
\node (n\i) [boxb=red!60!white] {};
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\node at ([shift={(90:5.4cm)}]B.center) (n\i) [boxc=green!60!white] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -9.45cm
\hskip 2.22cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape,
node distance = 1mm and 60mm,
  start chain = going below,
   boxc/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=12.7mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.6mm,
             on chain},
]
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\node (n\i) [boxc=violet!60!white] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to position the green boxes at the location of the B node.
I used the code

```
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\node at ([shift={(90:5.4cm)}]B.center) (n\i) [boxc=green!60!white] {};
```

But this did not work. How can this be done?

I could not figure out how to position them correctly. I had to do it manually, as I did for the violet boxes in another tikzpicture.

[image]

Comment: Your desired output is not clear for me ... But the optional argument of a `\node` command should be given before its mandatory ... like `\node[boxc=green!60!white] at ([shift={(90:5.4cm)}]B.center) (n\i)  {}`

Comment: @koleygrI tried your code, but the boxes are still positioned at A.center.

Comment: Try this code with `(B.center)` but with `(A.center)` too and see the difference: `\node[boxc=green!60!white,shift={(90:5.4cm)}] at (B.center) (n\i)  {};`

Comment: @koleygrThank you for your code. It places only one box in the desired location, but it does not apply the \foreach loop when I use:     \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\node[boxc=green!60!white,shift={(90:5.4cm)}] at (B.center) (n\i) {}; as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: I defined a dummy boxd style with no draw, no fill, no width/height. Then I applied the following code (which magically works).
    \node[boxd] at ([shift={(90:6.16cm)}]B.center){};
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
    \node at (B.center) (n\i) [boxc=green!60!white] {};    (refer to this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX2Rh.jpg)
Can somebody tell me why!! and can it be simplified.

Comment: You ar naming the node as `(n\i)` ... not placing at `(n\i)`   ... this means that it does printed in the same position every time (at shifted `(B.center)`)... You have to give something in the shift part (for example `\node[boxc=green!60!white,shift={(90:\i cm)}] at (B.center) (n\i) {}` or `\node[boxc=green!60!white,shift={(...)}] at (n\i) {}` etc)

Comment: @koleygrI tried your suggestions, but they did not work.

Comment: I think you should make clear where you expect the boxes ... a hand-drawed image or something could help.

Comment: Please do not get me wrong, but I have a feeling that you might be much better off if you specified what the ultimate aim of all these gymnastics is. Looking through your recent questions, it *seems* to me that you want to fill a distance with a chain of equidistant blocks of equal dimensions, whose color changes. If that is indeed the case, you may just ask one question on this and will get one answer that allows you to answer all these questions in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised your problem ... Your problem is that you have defined this style with the option `on chain` ... I removed that on a third same style named `boxd` and here is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape,
node distance = 1mm and 60mm,
  start chain = going below,
   boxa/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=7.1mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.96mm,
             on chain},
   boxb/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=7.1mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.96mm,
             on chain},
   boxc/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=12.7mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.6mm,
             on chain},
   boxd/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
             minimum width=6mm, minimum height=12.7mm,
             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.6mm},
]
\draw [line width=.4mm, black, dashed] (0,5.8) -- +(0:11) (0,0) -- +(0:11) node [pos=.28] (B) {\Large B} node [pos=.68] (A) {\Large A};

\node at ([shift={(90:5.4cm)}]A.center) (n1) [boxa=blue!60!white] {};
\node (n2) [boxa=blue!60!white] {};
\foreach \i in {3,...,6}
\node (n\i) [boxb=red!60!white] {};
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\node at ([shift={(90:5.4cm)}]B.center) (n\i) [boxc=green!60!white] {};
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
\node (l\i)at ($(0,-0.75)+({0.28*11},{-\i*1.5})$)  [boxd=green!60!white] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]